# How can I convert Array of Objects into Array of Array of Array

Tags: javascript, object, ecmascript-6, arrayofarrays

Hello Everyone I'm beginner in javascript I'm trying to convert from Array of objects into Array of array.I have tried some methods like Object.entries.But I didn't get the output what I expected.If anyone helps It will really helpful to me.Any kind of help would be appreciated.Thanks in advance....

```html
My Input:

  var data=[
           {name:'TOYA',price:34},
           {name:'TOYB',price:24},
           {name:'TOYC',price:444},
           {name:'TOYD',price:54}
        ];


Expected Output:

   var data=[
           ['TOYA',34],
           ['TOYB',24],
           ['TOYC',444],
           ['TOYD',54]
        ];
     
 But I got:
 
[ [ '0', { name: 'TOYA', price: 34 } ],
  [ '1', { name: 'TOYB', price: 24 } ],
  [ '2', { name: 'TOYC', price: 444 } ],
  [ '3', { name: 'TOYD', price: 54 } ] ]
  
 using Object.entries(data);
```

Comment: `[name:'c++',price:34]` not valid javascript, so you **can't** get that with any code

Comment: Would I be right in assuming that you mean `[["name", "c++"], ["price", 34]]`

Comment: so, what you want is an Array of Array ... not an Array of Array of Array

Comment: You need to use `Object.values`, see my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `Object.values` instead.

```js
var data=[
     {name:'TOYA',price:34},
     {name:'TOYB',price:24},
     {name:'TOYC',price:444},
     {name:'TOYD',price:54}
];

var newdata = [];
for (let obj of data) {
  newdata.push(Object.values(obj));
}
console.log(newdata)
```

Comment: @LearnforFun - I see you found out the problem

Answer (score 0):

```js
var data=[
           {name:'c++',price:34},
           {name:'java',price:24},
           {name:'python',price:444},
           {name:'php',price:54}
        ];


var result = Object.values(data).map(v => Object.values(v));
console.log(result)
```

Comment: Extremely Sorry for your inconvenience.I have changed my expected output.

Comment: @VigneshRaviKumar - the code now works as you require

Answer (score 0):

### You can use Object.values(arrayElement)

```
[{name:'c++',price:34},{name:'java',price:24},{name:'python',price:444},       {name:'php',price:54}].map((e)=>{return [Object.values(e)]})
```